# How to retrieve all children of a parent node in sybase

Tags: tree, structure, sybase, common-table-expression, sap-ase

I am having a table Employee which has employeeID and ManagerID. I would want to be able to drill down the tree structure from the ManagerID at the highest level and go down till the bottom of the tree. I understand that sybase does not support common table expression. Could you kindly suggest me ways of getting this information out when the levels of hierarchy is not known and will be different for different ManagerID's.

I am guessing we might need a recursive procedure but how do i return this tree structure list from a procedure.

I looked around similar questions on the same topic but was not able to get anything concrete. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.  Just a couple hints for tagging and details to include:  Sybase was a company, not a database, so it's better to add the tag for SAP Sybase product you are using.  It's also helpful to know the version of software you are using, as sometimes answers may differ based on the version you are running.  Since you asked about SAP Sybase ASE in a different question, I will go ahead and correct the tagging.  Also, it's not necessary to use all 5 available tags.

Comment: @MichaelGardner Thanks for helping me with the tagging. I hope to get some help now. I am using Sybase ASE 11/12/15- TDS 5.5. Since Common table expression is not supported here I would like suggestions as to how I can get the tree structure. Thanks in advance for your help. Will be more precise and accurate going forward.